# Apache PDFBox displaying data rows in new pages

Tags: pdfbox, vert.x

I'm creating a pdf with Apache PDFBox , I'm trying to read JSON values from a sample data class, to fill in rows, I put a check that if the data rows exceed the first page a new page should be created. However, pages are created but the data rows are not displayed on the created pages only displayed on the first page. Below is an excerpt of what I have done:

```java
float dataXPosition = 10f;
float dataYPosition = 560f;
float yPosition = 662f;
float margin = 100f;
float rowHeight = 20f;

JsonArray transactionList = SampleDataGenerator.generateSampleData().getJsonObject("data").getJsonArray("transactionList");

for (int i = 0; i < transactionList.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject transaction = transactionList.getJsonObject(i);

    if (dataYPosition - rowHeight < margin) {
        page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        dataYPosition = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - margin;
    }


    List<String> transactionValues = generateTransactionRow.doGenerateRow(transaction);

    for (String dataValues: transactionValues) {
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(HELVETICA, 6.5f);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(dataXPosition, dataYPosition);
        contentStream.showText(dataValues);
        contentStream.endText();
        dataXPosition += 100;
    }

    dataXPosition += -600;
    dataYPosition -= rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: The creation and the closing of `contentStream` is missing in the code.

Comment: Indeed, you create and add new pages but continue drawing the content on the original content stream. Close that stream in the `if (dataYPosition - rowHeight < margin)` code block and open a new one on the new page.

Comment: Thanks guys, opening a new content stream for the dataValues fixed the bug.